# Align a dropdown under text

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I need to have my dropdown options to open aligned under @item["name"]. At the moment it opens top left of table.

The project is in MVC

dropdown jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown").hide(); $("td.image img").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.image').siblings('.dropdown').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

dropdown css

```
.dropdown {
    height:10px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    position:relative;

}
```

table

```
<table class="diag" style="background: url('.png');border:none">
                <tbody>


                    @foreach (var item in Model.project)
                    {                            
                            @:<tr>
                     <td class="dropdown">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>Option 1</li>
                                                <li>Option 2</li>
                                             </ul>


                                        </td>

                        <td class="change"><div class="arrow-@item["change"]"></div></td>
                        <td class="image">
                            <img src="@item["image"]" />                               
                        </td>
                        <td class="name">@item["name"]</td>

                        @:</tr>
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap those two items in a `container`

and provide `float left` for items of container, they will automatically come under one another

sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y69XP/1/